# How to bake F-Curve using python?

Tags: python, animation

How can I bake f-curve using python for the active object?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

running `bpy.ops.graph.bake()` in the console rises a context error so i changed the context using one of [CoDEmanX seggestions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6105/5113) as follows :

```
import bpy

area = bpy.context.area
old_type = area.type

obj = bpy.context.active_object
curves = obj.animation_data.action.fcurves
for curve in curves:
    curve.select = True
    area.type = 'GRAPH_EDITOR'
    bpy.ops.graph.bake()
    area.type = old_type
```

this will bake all the F-curve of the active object